# removing strings until a condition is matched in python

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I have these string vectors

```
text1 = "  SPEECH Remarks at the European Economics and Financial Centre Remarks by Luis de Guindos, Vice-President of the ECB, at the European Economics and Financial Centre London, 2 March 2020 I am delighted to be here today at the European Economics and F'
text2 = "  SPEECH  The ECB’s response to the COVID-19 pandemic Remarks by Isabel Schnabel, Member of the Executive Board of the ECB, at a 24-Hour Global Webinar co-organised by the SAFE Policy Center on “The COVID-19 Crisis and Its Aftermath: Corporate Governance Implications and Policy Challenges” Frankfurt am Main, 16 April 2020 The COVID-19 pandemic is a shock of unprecedented intensity and severity. Th"
```

How I can remove all text before based on what dates I see in the text?

The expected result should be:

```
text1 = "I am delighted to be here today at the European Economics and F"

text2 = "The COVID-19 pandemic is a shock of unprecedented intensity and severity. Th"
```

**IMPORTANT**

Please note because I am handling a large number of similar documents, knowing all dates is not possible. I think the ideal solution should be able to identify the dates in order to remove the unnecessary text in the beginning.

Comment: Is there a set format as to how the dates should look? In other words, is it always going to follow the form `{day_arabic} {month_literal} {year_arabic}`?

Comment: Cannot be sure 100% as the documents I am checking are too many. But the few I checked were in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression

**Code**

```
import re

def remove_predate(text):
  '''Detect full and abbreviated dates i.e. 02 January 2020 and 02 Jan 2020'''

  date_pattern = r'(.*?)(\d{1,2}\s+(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\s+\d{4})'

  regex_detect = re.compile(date_pattern)
  m = regex_detect.match(text)

  if m:
    span = m.span(0)
    return text[span[1]:]  # skips text before and including date

  return text
```

**Tests**

```
print(remove_predate(text1))
print(remove_predate(text2))
```

**Output**

```
 I am delighted to be here today at the European Economics and F
 The COVID-19 pandemic is a shock of unprecedented intensity and severity. Th
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regexps:

```
import re
month_names = ('January', …, 'December') # fill the missing names
date_regexp = r'\d{1,2}\s+(' + '|'.join(month_names) + r')\s+\d{4}'
rx = re.compile('.*?' + date_regexp)
text1 = re.sub(rx, '', text1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to understand the **format of dates** in your speeches & text prior to searching for the,, they can be written as 01/10/2020, 01 Oct 2020, 1-10-2020 in various speeches. If you can find the fixed date format, regex can be used to find for the date.

Regex expression for dates with slashes, from [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=17)

```
^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$
```

Regex expression for dates without slashes but spaces, from [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=405)

```
^((31(?!\ (Feb(ruary)?|Apr(il)?|June?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov)(ember)?)))|((30|29)(?!\ Feb(ruary)?))|(29(?=\ Feb(ruary)?\ (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])\ (Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Apr(il)?|Ju((ly?)|(ne?))|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov|Dec)(ember)?)\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$
```